# same classes multiple times how to get object using index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an element's value based on the class and the index that it was created.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A324T/3/):

Code (not working)

```
alert($('.demo-default').length); //works

//alert ( $('.demo-default').get(2).val()); 
x = $('.demo-default').get(2);
alert(x).val();

//alert ( $('.demo-default').index(2 ).val()); //NW
```

WORKING :

http://jsfiddle.net/A324T/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `x` to invoke `val()` on it, or use `.value`

With

```
x = $('.demo-default').get(2); //x is DOM element.
```

Use

```
x.value; //Prop on DOM element
```

With

```
x = $('.demo-default').eq(2); //x is Jq object.
```

Use

```
x.val(); //method on jq object
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the DOM element.

You want to use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you use `alert` function wrong.
Also, `jQuery.get()` method will return a DOM element. `val()` method works only with jQuery objects. To fetch the value, simply use `value` property.

```
alert(x.value);
```